# Server error on my Meteor App?

Tags: node.js, meteor, modulus.io

Hi I am currently using Modulus.io to host my meteor application, but it keep crashing.

it is my first time doing hosting, so I can not very good at reading the Log, can someone tell me what is wrong ?

```
    at /mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1191:22
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:180:16)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at [object Object].Base.__executeAllServerSpecificErrorCallbacks (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:373:29)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/repl_set/ha.js:469:10)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:567:84)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14

npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start: `node ../../main`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ../../main
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-46-generic
npm ERR! command "/mnt/home/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/node" "/mnt/home/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /mnt/app/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/app/programs/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Found package.json: ./programs/server/package.json
Start script specified in package.json: node ../../main
Initializing Node.js 0.10.36
Now using node v0.10.36
Running command: npm start

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start /mnt/app/programs/server
> node ../../main

Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync
FS.HTTP.unmount:
{}
Registered HTTP method URLs:
/cfs/files/:collectionName/:id/:filename
/cfs/files/:collectionName/:id
/cfs/files/:collectionName

/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_scram.js:165
            if(r.done == false) {
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of null
    at /mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_scram.js:165:17
    at /mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1191:22
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:180:16)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at [object Object].Base.__executeAllServerSpecificErrorCallbacks (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:373:29)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/repl_set/ha.js:469:10)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:567:84)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14

npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start: `node ../../main`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ../../main
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-46-generic
npm ERR! command "/mnt/home/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/node" "/mnt/home/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /mnt/app/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/app/programs/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Found package.json: ./programs/server/package.json
Start script specified in package.json: node ../../main
Initializing Node.js 0.10.36
Now using node v0.10.36
Running command: npm start

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start /mnt/app/programs/server
> node ../../main

Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync
FS.HTTP.unmount:
{}
Registered HTTP method URLs:
/cfs/files/:collectionName/:id/:filename
/cfs/files/:collectionName/:id
/cfs/files/:collectionName

/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_scram.js:165
            if(r.done == false) {
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of null
    at /mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/auth/mongodb_scram.js:165:17
    at /mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1191:22
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9)
    at [object Object].g (events.js:180:16)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at [object Object].Base.__executeAllServerSpecificErrorCallbacks (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:373:29)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/repl_set/ha.js:469:10)
    at Server.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:567:84)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/mnt/app/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14

npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start: `node ../../main`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the meteor-dev-bundle package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ../../main
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls meteor-dev-bundle
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-46-generic
npm ERR! command "/mnt/home/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/node" "/mnt/home/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /mnt/app/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/app/programs/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Found package.json: ./programs/server/package.json
Start script specified in package.json: node ../../main
Initializing Node.js 0.10.36
Now using node v0.10.36
Running command: npm start

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 start /mnt/app/programs/server
> node ../../main
```

Message when i deployed it

```
Welcome to Modulus
You are logged in as karlson
[?] Are you sure you want to use project Peer2Pass? (yes) yes
Meteor project detected...

WARNING: The output directory is under your source tree.

21.2 MB written
Uploading project...
Upload progress [===================] 100%
Deploying project into Node.js runtime...
Starting build.
Creating directories for build environment.
Downloading source.
Executing build.
Package found: /app/.demeteorized/bundle/programs/server/package.json
Installing node 0.10.36
Installing npm 3.3.5
Installing packages from /app/.demeteorized/bundle/programs/server/package.json
WARN: npm-shrinkwrap.json will override dependencies declared in package.json.

> fibers@1.0.5 install /mnt/input/app/.demeteorized/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 /mnt/input/app/.demeteorized/bundle/programs/server
├── fibers@1.0.5 
├── semver@4.1.0 
├─┬ source-map-support@0.2.8 
│ └─┬ source-map@0.1.32 
│   └── amdefine@0.1.0 
└── underscore@1.5.2 

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
v0.10.36
deploy -> v0.10.36
Uploading completed build.
Provisioning and deploying bundle to servos...
```

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your node version and the version meteor is expecting. You have modulus tagged here, is that because you've deployed to modulus for this error? What about locally? Do you get these errors locally?

Comment: I suggest a full meteor reinstall :)

Comment: I don't get these error locally! but the site work sometimes!

Comment: reinstall? u mean create another project at Modulus and deploy again?

Comment: Have you run "meteor update"?

Comment: trying it now and see if it works

Comment: done it and it doesnt work....

Comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4148 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-382

Comment: what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Form your comments it sounds like you've run a `meteor update`, so I'll assume your application has been upgraded to a Meteor 1.4.x release. Meteor 1.4 requires Node 4.4.7, but from your logs we can see that the Modulus CLI is using Node 0.10.36. Try forcing the Modulus CLI to use the newer Meteor supported node and npm versions as follows:

From the command line:

```
modulus deploy --node-version 4.4.3 --npm-version 3.10.5
```

**or**

In your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.7",
    "npm": "3.10.5"
  }
}
```